# how to assign the text-block text value form resource file in codebehind

Tags: wpf, xaml

For a textblock i can assign  the text from XAML in the below format  from my resource file

```
<TextBlock  Text="{x:Static res:Strings.Page1Text1}" ></TextBlock>
```

where Strings the  resourcefile name (class name) and Page1Text1 is the key ,

how to do the same in codebehind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name your text block and then you can use it in your code behind:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="myTextBlock" ... ></TextBlock>
```

in your code behind...

```
myTextBlock.text = Strings.Page1Text1;
```

The strings table should be available to your code behind.